# QTP : Sendkey method with the combination of Ctrl key doesn't work

Tags: vbscript, qtp, sendkeys

I wanted to use the short cut key in VBA scripting instead of clicking on the objects.
So I used this code below ( ^F6 ) to press "ctrl+F6". But it didn't work and displays a syntax error.

```
SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("Aufteiler anlegen : Einstieg").SendKey  ^F6
```

However, +F6 for "SHIFT + F6" worked perfectly.  Could anyone figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

QTP doesn't translate `^` to control, instead it uses a [special constant](http://www.vietnamesetestingboard.org/zbxe/?document_srl=477821) `micCtrl`.
Something like this might work (untested)

```
With SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("Aufteiler anlegen : Einstieg")
    .SendKey micCtrlDown
    .SendKey micF6
    .SendKey micCtrlUp
End With
```